# How to log in a user right after signing up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, registration

I know I should put the code in the create action of the users controller, but I'm not sure what code I should put. I also assume it should call the create action in my sessions controller, but again I'm not sure how...

By the way I tried `render :template => 'sessions/create'` in the create action of the users controller, but I get this error when signing up:

```
Template is missing

Missing template sessions/create with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:rjs, :rhtml, :erb, :rxml, :builder]} in view paths "/rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views", "/rubyprograms/dreamstill/vendor/plugins/facebox_render/app/views"
```

This is all in my application controller:

```
protected 
  # Returns the currently logged in user or nil if there isn't one
  def current_user
    return unless session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) 
  end


  # Make current_user available in templates as a helper
  helper_method :current_user

  # Filter method to enforce a login requirement
  # Apply as a before_filter on any controller you want to protect
  def authenticate
    logged_in? ? true : access_denied
  end

  # Predicate method to test for a logged in user    
  def logged_in?
    current_user.is_a? User
  end

  # Make logged_in? available in templates as a helper
  helper_method :logged_in?

  def access_denied
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        flash[:alert] = "You must log in to peform this action."
        redirect_to root_path
      end

      format.js do
        render_to_facebox(:partial => 'sessions/login_box')
      end
    end
     false
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere in your controllers you have something that looks like this:

```
user = User.new
# set attributes
user.save
render :template => 'sessions/create' # Probably based on your question
```

All you need to do is update the `session` to:

```
user = User.new
# set attributes
if(user.save)
   session[:user_id] = user.id
   # Send them somewhere useful
else
   # Handle the error
end
```

They're signed in once `session[:user_id]` is set.

Comment: this causes an `undefined method` error for `value` in this line:
`current_user.votes_for(video).value == 1`

Comment: That has nothing to do with signing in, that just means that `current_user.votes_for(video)` is probably `nil`. Have you set `@current_user` properly anywhere?

Comment: Isn't that what `def current_user` does? `current_user.votes_for(video)` isn't `nil` if I log in regularly... it's `nil` only when, using your code, I'm logged in right after signing up

Comment: My `current_user` is essentially `@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])` so you can try explicitly setting `@current_user` after `user.save`.

Comment: ALW's solution should get all the rails internals properly set up, setting `session[:user_id]` should ensure that that login persists across connections.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm going to do an email confirmation... it's probably the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Technically?

In your controller, after you create your user, this code:

`@current_user = user`

should get you going (looks like you're using restful_authentication).

Now, whether it's a good idea to log in a user automatically without verifying their email address / whatever else is up for debate.

Answer (score 0):

You seem that you just begin with Rails right ? I would highly recommend that you use a gem like Devise to handle your user registrations.

However, if you insist on doing it manually, you would just need to create a session variable that verifies whether a user is logged in or not. Then, you can add a helper like current_user, to get the user if user session shows he/she is logged in.

I see that you have a sessions controller there. Are you trying to use restful_authentication ? If so, once more i highly recommend switching to Devise :)

OLD CODE USING RESTFUL AUTHENTICATION - SESSIONS CONTROLLER

```
# This controller handles the login/logout function of the site.  
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  # Be sure to include AuthenticationSystem in Application Controller instead
  include AuthenticatedSystem

  # render new.erb.html
  def new
  end

  def create
    logout_keeping_session!
    user = User.authenticate(params[:login], params[:password])
    if user
      # Protects against session fixation attacks, causes request forgery
      # protection if user resubmits an earlier form using back
      # button. Uncomment if you understand the tradeoffs.
      # reset_session
      self.current_user = user
      new_cookie_flag = (params[:remember_me] == "1")
      handle_remember_cookie! new_cookie_flag
      flash[:notice] = "Logged in successfully"
      redirect_to :controller=>'Town'
    else
      note_failed_signin
      @login       = params[:login]
      @remember_me = params[:remember_me]
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    logout_killing_session!
    flash[:notice] = "You have been logged out."
    redirect_back_or_default('/')
  end

protected
  # Track failed login attempts
  def note_failed_signin
    flash[:error] = "Couldn't log you in as '#{params[:login]}'"
    logger.warn "Failed login for '#{params[:login]}' from #{request.remote_ip} at #{Time.now.utc}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the restful authentication with the built in sessions. I already have all of that. Let me post my code.

Comment: ok I posted the code in my application controller... what could I use there to login the user right after signing in?

Comment: I don't think sessions/create is a get action, but rather a post one. You can check that by "rake routes". I think you would need to redirect to something like /sessions/new after registration. Check your routes pls.

Comment: In restful authentication(if i remember correctly), you just get the current_user after the log in process happens. I am going to paste the code of a very old project of mine, using resful authentication, it may help

Comment: Btw, i don't think you should have any such code in your application controller.